# Proving $\operatorname{rank}(f,a)=\operatorname{rank}(f'(a))$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $U$ be an open set of $\mathbb{R}^m$ and consider the following differentiable map:
>
> $$f:U\to\mathbb{R}^m$$
>
> Let $a\in U$
>
> then
>
> $\operatorname{rank}(f,a)=\operatorname{rank}(f'(a))$

I have been using this latter expression for years. Whenever I wanted to compute the rank of a function at a point I would compute the derivative and check the linear independent lines of that matrix. I can understand that if I take the derivative of $f$ at $a$ I get the direction of f at each component, so it makes intuitively sense that the rank of the derivative must be the rank of f. However I have been looking for a proof of this claim in books and on the internet and I found nothing.

Question:

How is $\operatorname{rank}(f,a)=\operatorname{rank}(f'(a))$ proven?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's your definition of the rank of a differentiable map?

Comment: @Bernard        Number of linearly independent lines.

Comment: Which lines? I do not understand.

Comment: @Bernard You are going to say this is part of a definition, right? But is there any proof?   I meant the lines of the matrix.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand. I do not know what the rank of $f$ is. For me, it's a concept of linear algebra, so it has a meaning for $f'$.

Comment: @Bernard My question is exactly that. Why does it have a meaning for $f'$? How do you prove that?

Comment: Because the differential *is* a linear map.

Comment: @Bernard          Why not evaluate the rank of the matrix $f(a)$? Instead of $f'(a)$

Comment: $f(a)$ is just a column matrix so its rank  is just $0$ or $1$. It has nothing to do with the differential, which is represented by the Jabobian matrix.

Comment: @Bernard             So how can one say that the rank of $f$ is the same as the rank of $f'$ at a? What is backing up that statement? What is the proof?

Comment: Is this an implication of the mean value theorem? Or something of the sort?

Comment: Probably, it is by definition. *Per se*, the rank of $f$ (fifferentiable or not) is meaningless, as far as I know.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is (or not) an implication of the M.V.T.?